# What does it mean???? FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Tags: dart

Im practicing a dart exercise. the code is fine, works in the cloud no problem with it. but from time to time Im getting this error.

FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

what does it mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511568/unhandled-exception-formatexception-invalid-radix-10-number-at-character-1

Comment: The error means that somewhere you tried and failed to parse a `String` as a radix-10 (aka base-10) number.